# How to check Ethernet in Linux?

Tags: c, linux, ethernet

I need the test case for Ethernet in Linux using C code to check `eth0`. If `eth0` is down, we enable the net then check if up and the test is passed.

Answer (score 13):

To check if the link is up, try something like this. It works without root privileges.

```
#include <stdio.h>        // printf
#include <string.h>       // strncpy
//#include <sys/socket.h> // AF_INET
#include <sys/ioctl.h>    // SIOCGIFFLAGS
#include <errno.h>        // errno
#include <netinet/in.h>   // IPPROTO_IP
#include <net/if.h>       // IFF_*, ifreq

#define ERROR(fmt, ...) do { printf(fmt, __VA_ARGS__); return -1; } while(0)

int CheckLink(char *ifname) {
    int state = -1;
    int socId = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_IP);
    if (socId < 0) ERROR("Socket failed. Errno = %d\n", errno);

    struct ifreq if_req;
    (void) strncpy(if_req.ifr_name, ifname, sizeof(if_req.ifr_name));
    int rv = ioctl(socId, SIOCGIFFLAGS, &if_req);
    close(socId);

    if ( rv == -1) ERROR("Ioctl failed. Errno = %d\n", errno);

    return (if_req.ifr_flags & IFF_UP) && (if_req.ifr_flags & IFF_RUNNING);
}

int main() {
    printf("%d\n", CheckLink("eth0"));
}
```

If IFF_UP is set, it means interface is up (see ifup). If IFF_RUNNING is set then interface is plugged.
I also tried using the ethtool ioctl call, but it failed when the gid was not root. But just for the log:

```
...
#include <asm/types.h>     // __u32
#include <linux/ethtool.h> // ETHTOOL_GLINK
#include <linux/sockios.h> // SIOCETHTOOL
...
int CheckLink(char *ifname) {
    ...
    struct ifreq if_req;
    (void) strncpy( if_req.ifr_name, ifname, sizeof(if_req.ifr_name) );

    struct ethtool_value edata;
    edata.cmd = ETHTOOL_GLINK;
    if_req.ifr_data = (char*) &edata;

    int rv = ioctl(socId, SIOCETHTOOL, &if_req);
    ...

    return !!edata.data;
}
```

Comment: @TrueY: One question, assuming I just want to get the status of the link what is the difference between getting it via ETHTOOL_GLINK vs SIOCGIFFLAGS? Does `ethtool_value.data == 1` implies `IFF_UP` and `IFF_RUNNING`. I have asked a detailed question on this at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33039485/siocethtool-vs-siocgmiiphy-vs-siocgifflags. Please let me know your thoughts on it

Comment: @Vivek It was quite long time ago, but I think that if edata.data == 1 then interface is UP and RUNNING.

Comment: Can I use the same in virtual environment? How can I set interface down in virtual environment? I am running test program which checks IFF_RUNNING flag at every 500 milliseconds. I am not receiving interface down, it always finds IFF_RUNNING flag set. Need help in this matter.

Answer (score 3):

The network interfaces can be seen in `sysfs`: `/sys/class/net/eth[x]`. There you can check the link, interface status, and more.

Answer (score 2):

You may want to take advantage of libudev to get around in /sys:

```
http://www.signal11.us/oss/udev/
```

Answer (score 1):

I simply check if an Ip address is assigned to the network card.

You can use something like this to check if lan is up in the given network card (say **eth0**) :

```
/sbin/ifconfig eth0| grep 'inet addr:' | wc -l
```

This should simply return 0 or 1 based on whether or not an ip address is assigned to the nic.

Also you may use **Yann Ramin's** method to list out all the nic's & perform the check.

---

I missed out noticing you are looking for a c code. Maybe adding a tag would be good.

Either ways, I think you can look at the same file (**ifconfig**) manually in c by reading it for an ip.

Answer (score 1):

As this question is somewhat important, I'll add another answer despite its extreme age. You can read the contents of /sys/class/net/eth0/operstate which will simply contain the string "up\n" or "down\n".