# What is the difference between IFF_UP and IFF_RUNNING?

Tags: c, linux, network-programming

These two flags are often set together. What is the difference between them?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

From [Linux Device Drivers 3](http://www.xml.com/ldd/chapter/book/ch14.html#t3):

> IFF_UP
>        This flag is read-only for the driver. The kernel turns it on when the interface is active and ready to transfer packets.
>
> ...
>
> IFF_RUNNING
>
> This flag indicates that the interface is up and running. It is mostly
>   present for BSD compatibility; the kernel makes little use of it. Most
>   network drivers need not worry about IFF_RUNNING.

Digging a bit deeper, it seems that there *is* one significant difference:

`IFF_RUNNING` is supposed to reflect the *operational* status on a network interface, rather than its administrative one. To provide an example, an Ethernet interface may be brought `UP` by the administrator (e.g. `ifconfig eth0 up`), but it will not be considered operational (i.e. `RUNNING` as per RFC2863) if the cable is not plugged in.

Answer (score 7):

To check if the ethernet cable is really connected to the network You should check IFF_RUNNIG. IFF_UP means that the system allocated the resources for the interface.

Please find detailed code how "ip link show" and "ethtool eth0" checks for link is up [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4231507/how-to-check-ethernet-in-linux/15905276#15905276).