# Check if LAN is plugged

Tags: c, linux

i want to check if the LAN cable is plugged in on a linux system, is there any file in /sys or /proc that i can check (i would like to do it in C)?

Comment: Possibly see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4231507/how-to-check-ethernet-in-linux

Comment: I just posted a solution @ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4231507/how-to-check-ethernet-in-linux. Maybe you could use the same.

Answer (score 5):

To check if a cable is plugged you can look in /sys/class/net/

For ex. for eth0 connection:

```
$ grep "" /sys/class/net/eth0/*
/sys/class/net/eth0/carrier:0
/sys/class/net/eth0/operstate:down
```

As you can see, cable isn't plugged.
if it was plugged i was getting:

```
/sys/class/net/eth0/carrier:1
/sys/class/net/eth0/operstate:up
```

Comment: sure thing, happy to give a hand when i can :)

Answer (score 2):

Run the `ifconfig` command which will show all the interfaces connected.