# SIOCETHTOOL vs SIOCGMIIPHY vs SIOCGIFFLAGS

Tags: c, linux, driver, ethernet, ioctl

After some search on the Internet,I came to know that, following are the list of options available to get/set parameters to the ethernet interface.

1. `SIOCETHTOOL`
2. `SIOCGMIIPHY`
3. `SIOCGIFFLAGS`

I even saw some 'stackoverflow' questions regarding the usage of [SIOCETHTOOL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4231507/how-to-check-ethernet-in-linux). But the questions I have are:

1. Comparison of these three interfaces (means API's) in terms of the features they offer and support in multiple kernels. When should one of these options should be preferred over the others.
2. I hardly find documentations for `SIOCETHTOOL` and `SIOCGMIIPHY`. Can you please point to the same?